# Recursive folder tree in PHP

Tags: php, recursion, tree, treeview

I want to make a folder tree array in php. I coded something, it is almost done but there is some issue.

So, all files and folders should be in same json as they are in folders. Here my codes:

```
function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array(), $counter = 0 ) {
    $files = scandir($dir);

    foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $path = realpath($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
        if (!is_dir($path)) {
            $results[] = array('name'=>$path,'type'=>'file');
            
        } else if ($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            $results[] = array('name'=>$path,'type'=>'folder','subfolders'=>array());
            
            getDirContents($path, $results[count($results)]['subfolders']);
            
        }
    }

    return $results;
}


print_r(json_encode(getDirContents('./')));
```

The result is like below. But it has subfolders label at different place. For example; subfolder test4 should be in test2 subfolder buut it is district from test2 folder.

```
[
   {
      "name":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\test.php",
      "type":"file"
   },
   {
      "name":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\test.txt",
      "type":"file"
   },
   {
      "name":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\test1",
      "type":"folder",
      "subfolders":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "subfolders":[
         {
            "name":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\test1\\test2",
            "type":"folder",
            "subfolders":[
               
            ]
         },
         {
            "subfolders":[
               {
                  "name":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\test1\\test2\\test4",
                  "type":"folder",
                  "subfolders":[
                     
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "subfolders":null
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\test1\\test3.txt",
            "type":"file"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\test_1.php",
      "type":"file"
   }
]
```

Result should be like that:

```
[
  {
    "folder1": {
      "name": "test1.txt",
      "type": "file",
      "subfolders": {
        "subfolder1": {
          "name": "test1",
          "type": "folder"
        },
        "subfolder2": {
          "name": "test2",
          "type": "folder",
          "subfolders": {
            "subfolder3": {
              "name": "test3",
              "type": "folder"
            },
            "subfile":{
              "name":"test3.txt"
              "type":"file"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I hope I could explain my situation. At the result, datas is not in one back datas.

Comment: _"my folder tree type should be like below"_ - Your expected result is invalid JSON. Please show us a valid example.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried to explain more, I could not excatly make json format what I want.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I edited the post again, I could add json type eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here when you call `getDirContents($path, $results[count($results)]['subfolders']);` recursivelly, you provide second parameter with wrong index of array. When you store the first folder to `$results` it has index in array = 0. But then you use `count()` function to get number of records from `$results` array it returns `1` not `0`. Also I think you have disabled notice error reporting and you just havent seen it.
Replace count($results) with `array_key_last` or `count($results) - 1`

Comment: So many thanks Roman Krut, actually you are right. I changed what you mean, and it works excatly ! I should have gotten an error at last index but I did not get any error. That solved my problem, thanks again...

Comment: My advice is to use error_reporting(E_ALL); on development.
Put it at the beginning of your script and you should see noticec.